# How to get again mysql NOTES.txt output after installed it using helm and bitnami repo

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I am new using bitnami, helm and k8s. I have installed the mysql using bitnami repo and helm according to this [page](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/infrastructure/mysql/get-started/add-repo/). After that, it was shown a output with some helper (commands), which were generated using this [template](https://github.com/juan131/charts-1/blob/e6a3f922394f35f7012f33646cee789da0a7e9cd/bitnami/mysql/templates/NOTES.txt).

Q: Is there a way to see/generate these outputs again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `helm get notes <release_name>`

https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_notes/#synopsis